# Wrapper-daemon handling wrapped program(s) output

Tags: javascript, c, linux, daemon

I have a small hobby project where I'm writing a 'wrapper'-daemon in linux, in C. That is, it's purpose is to start, monitor, issue commands to and stop other programs. The daemon also serves up a web interface where users can log in and manipulate the running programs(s).

The way it's set up right now is that whenever a program writes to its stdout, this output is redirected to a pipe. Whenever someone then accesses the program through the web interface, the web interface starts polling the daemon through XMLHttpRequest()'s, the daemon then checks if something has been written to the pipe and sends back a response with whatever was in the pipe at the time.

The main issue is when I have two (or more) users logged in and trying to interact with the same program. Since the web interface effectively polls the pipe for anything written, whenever several users are logged in and monitoring the same program, the output of that program is randomely sent to one of the users. This is obviously bad.

The one solution to solving this that I'm contemplating at the moment is to timestamp all output that a program generates and store this information in something like a database. When the web interface then polls the daemon with a timestamp, the daemon simply collects all the output that has been written since and sends this back.

I think something like the above solution would solve the multi-user issue but I thought I would take a stab and query the Stack Overflow community about this problem. Is there some better solution to a problem like this? (Given I've managed to describe the problem in a somewhat understandable way that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want *all returning* users to be presented with all of the output from every given program on their next login, I don't think that storing the information in a database is necessary. That also sounds like it would be a bit on the expensive side.

What you need is some kind of session implementation and tokenization system where users 'subscribe' to certain output streams. When `select()` or `poll()` fires on the pipe fd, that data should be written to all subscribers of that particular process.

You could implement both, where data that did not reach a subscribed user would be stored for displaying upon their next login. That need not be a complex or even SQL database, a simple key => value pair would work like (example just storing it in an INI file:

```
[process-token]
TIMESTAMP.SEC.(...) = "string"
```

I was initially confused with your question, but after reading it again I realized that we are working on nearly identical projects. Mine is attaching a simple serial client to a psuedo TTY which feeds something very similar to Ajaxterm. It facilitates access to consoles to paravirtualized Xen virtual machines.

Comment: I'll take a look at the per-user streams, thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

in abstract, you have a sort of queue that forks.  programs on the host produce output that gets enqueued at the head and users each consume from their own tail.  the "consume" part is a little funny, because you don't want to "forget" content until all interested users have seen it.  Tim Post suggests using a simple queue per user-stream, with the producer enqueueing to all "subscribed" queues.  The other approach is a queue-per-producer, with a cursor to mark how far a user has already seen.  The latter approach is parsimonious in that it doesn't replicate anything, but does force you to figure out when everyone has seen trailing content so you can forget it.

I think I'd try the latter approach, and just punt on forgetting.  that is, always store all output forever.  this is potentially quite attractive to users, as well - after all, what terminal emulator doesn't have a generous-sized scroll-back buffer?  it's more storage, but storage is embarassingly cheap these days.

I don't think using a DB is necessarily a bad idea.  you might, for instance, want to associate a timestamp with output as it is produced, or to perform searches within the content.  tracking how far in a stream users have seen would most likely be done by rowid, but users might appreciate a "show me output for the last hour" kind of interface.  storing each queue as a table, with rows indexed by time would be a natural workload for a DB, pretty efficient in space and time.  but the basic no-forget queue could be done very simply as a file-per-stream with user positions stored as offset.

Tim's approach, with per-user streams, does a bit more work in the producer's context, depending on how often a producer has multiple subscribers.  not a viable approach if your producers are like twitter: being watched by millions of users ;)  but his stream-per-user approach could also not bother garbage-collecting, could also include the DB and timestamp ideas.

Comment: Ah, yes, It's not anywhere near Twitter-load. I think I'm going to check out Tim's approach. Thank you for your input.